# Is it possible to filter a TextFile in listview in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, filter, text-files

For example the value in my Textfile

```
1.Description=DATABASESECRIPTION1
1.name = TEST1
1.age = 18

2.Description=DATABASESECRIPTION2
2.name = TEST1
2.age = 14

3.Description=DATABASESECRIPTION3
3.name = TEST1
3.age = 18
```

i only wanna see

```
1.Description=DATABASESECRIPTION1
2.Description=DATABASESECRIPTION2
3.Description=DATABASESECRIPTION3
```

and i only wanna show the value of description in a textfile how can i do this ?
How can i filter this.

my code

```
Stream mystream;
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((mystream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    string strfilname= openFileDialog.FileName;
                    string filetext = File.ReadAllText(strfilname);
                    ListVIew.Text = filetext;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply you can check if your line contains "description". if so, take rest of text from "=" char. check this:

```
  var list = new List<string>();
        var text = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt");
        foreach (var s in text)
        {
            if (s.Contains("Description"))
            {
                var desc = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("=") + 1);
                list.Add(desc);
            }
        }
```

LINQ:

```
list.AddRange(from s in text where s.Contains("Description") select s.Substring(s.IndexOf("=") + 1));
```

here is result: [image]

Comment: I only get the last description not all the Description

Comment: what do you mean only 2.description? i updated my answer. i got every description from txt file. also i added linq version. @user7103900

Answer (score 0):

Filter for lines that contain '.Description='.

```
var fileLines = filetext.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
ListVIew.Text = fileLines.Where(l => l.Contains(".Description="));
```