# How to filter values read from a text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, text-files

I want to get a couple of values from a textfile in C#. Example:

```
1.sex=male
1.name=barack
1.lastname=obama
1.age = 55

2.sex=female
2.name= kelly
2.lastname=clinton
2.age = 24

3.sex = male
3.firstname= mike
3.lastname= james
3.age= 19
```

I only want to get all the "name", "lastname" and ages from the textFile, not the "sex". How can I filter this? I have tried something like this, but it only shows 1 value.

```
var list = new List<string>();

var text = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jal\Desktop\Test.text");
foreach (var s in text)
{              
    if (s.Contains("Name"))
    {                       
        if (s.Contains("Name"))
        {
            var desc = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("=") + 1);
            list.Add(desc);
            ListView.Items.Add(desc);                         
        }  
    }
}
```

I found this code on Stack Overflow, but it doesn't get all of the values I want.

Comment: @nozzleman you see my code i tried allot but no results

Comment: The code seems correct to me (although you repeated an if twice) but this should work check your text file for typos also check and see that "text" has all the lines in the file. Place breakpoints in different locations and see where is the problem.

Comment: why double if check for `Name` ?

Comment: @Emad i wanna see all the names lastnames and ages i only see name how can i see everything the code does not what i want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to filter a TextFile in listview in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377293/is-it-possible-to-filter-a-textfile-in-listview-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Ok now your question is more clear. Do you want to show this to user or you want to create a class of this data to use for more processing?

Comment: @Emad create a class for more proccesing

Comment: @Badiparmagi not realy the code on that page doesnt do what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var names = new List<string>();
var lastnames = new List<string>();

var text = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jal\Desktop\Test.text");
foreach (var s in text)
{
    if (s.Contains("lastname"))
    {        
        var lastname = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("=") + 1);
        lastnames.Add(lastname);
        continue;
    }
    if (s.Contains("name"))
    {        
        var name = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("=") + 1);
        names.Add(name);
        continue;
    }        
}
```

And in same way you can add another properties.

Comment: The *if* statement for `s.Contains("lastname")` wont be reached as you have `s.Contains("name")` before. Need to write `if (s.Contains("lastname"))` first.

Comment: @MarkBenovsky good point, I improved it. And continue is needed.

Comment: @BWA the first if statement goes good but the second if statement shows all the values in the textFile

Comment: @bf.a What do you mean, shows all values? At the end of each line is ENTER?

Answer (score 0):

s.Contains("Name") won't ever be true on this case because it's case-sensitive, and your string in the file is "name".

Try using s.Contains("name")

But you would be better off using a Regex for this kind of thing.